# Match 2 dataframes within a specified tolerance range of DateTimeIndex while keeping a unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

`df1`:

```
Time (index)              Value
2016-10-28 10:27:00+00:00 5    
2016-10-28 10:28:00+00:00 12    
2016-10-28 10:29:00+00:00 20    
2016-10-28 10:30:00+00:00 34    
2016-10-28 10:31:00+00:00 1    
2016-10-28 10:32:00+00:00 30    
2016-10-28 10:33:00+00:00 20    
2016-10-28 10:34:00+00:00 10
```

`df2`:

```
Time (index)              Value
2016-10-28 10:27:00+00:00 56    
2016-10-28 10:31:00+00:00 72
```

How would I find the rows in `df1` that have a time within 1mins inclusive of a row in `df2`? So that my result is:

`df3`:

```
Time (index)              Value
2016-10-28 10:27:00+00:00 5    
2016-10-28 10:28:00+00:00 12    
2016-10-28 10:30:00+00:00 34    
2016-10-28 10:31:00+00:00 1    
2016-10-28 10:32:00+00:00 30
```

I've looked at all sorts of merging, joining etc. but it's all crazy stuff to a web developer!

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

How might an answer be extended to include an arbitrary identifier as follows:

`df3`:

```
Time (index)              Value  Id
2016-10-28 10:27:00+00:00 5      1 
2016-10-28 10:28:00+00:00 12     1
2016-10-28 10:30:00+00:00 34     2
2016-10-28 10:31:00+00:00 1      2
2016-10-28 10:32:00+00:00 30     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to transform the index of `df2` to that of `df1` with the allowed tolerance limit of 1 minute by passing `method='nearest'` which has support for the entered `tolerance` range.

Drop the missing values (`NaN's`) from these and realign `df1` based on the obtained indices later.

```
matches = df2.reindex(df1.index, method='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1m'))
finite_matches = matches.dropna()
df3 = df1.loc[finite_matches.index]
```

[image]

***Note:***

Starting with `v0.20.0`, [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) *(currently it does only backward lookup)* could also be used to achieve the same thing in the following manner:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1m'), direction='nearest')
```

***Edit:***

To include identifiers corresponding to similar valued groupings, you can take the difference between consecutive cells obtained from the `matches` dataframe after dropping nulls from it.

Wherever these do not equate to zero, their cumulative sum gets computed causing breaks (transition in outcome) at any `False` value encountered while traversing the boolean series.

```
df3.assign(Id=finite_matches.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
```

[image]

Comment: Very neat answer!

Comment: Appreciate that :-)

Comment: @NickilMaveli I've added an extension to the original question - do you have any tips left in your magic hat?

Comment: Thanks again @NickilMaveli

Answer (score 0):

One easy, inefficient though, is to check for all pairs of rows.

```
matching = df1["Time"].apply(lambda r1: df2["Time"].apply(lambda r2: abs((r2 - r1)) <= pd.Timedelta('1 minute')).sum())
```

This will give you how many times the row from df1 has matched a row from df2 with 1 minute difference.

Next you can just filter by `matching > 0`

```
result = df1[matching > 0]
```